# View contents of Angular template on page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been looking for a while now and cannot seem to find the right answer to this question and I was hoping you all could help.

What I am trying to do is pass in a URL, through JSON, to my angular directive so I can display the contents/code in a template on the screen.

I am trying to create a directive cheat sheet, similar in design to that of Bootstrap's documentation page: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

I have tried using `ng-bind-html`, but that only displays the URL I pass in.

My question is, can I pass in a template URL through JSON to a directive and have the contents/code of that file be displayed on the screen? Or do I need to copy all the code into the JSON file directly pass a string representation of the code to the directive?

**EDIT**

Here is a sample of the JSON file I am building:

```
{"id":"number-picker",
  "title":"Number Picker",
  "description":"An input box used to communicate a numeric value from the client to the server",
  "code":"/js/directives/templates/number-picker.html"}
```

And here is a section of the directive I'm building:

```
<h2>{{directive.title}}</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <span class="bold">Description:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <span ng-bind-html="directive.description"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<p><span class="bold">Code:</span>
    <div class="code">
        <div ng-bind-html="directive.code"></div>
    </div>
</p>
```

Comment: could you show a coding example of what you are trying right now? Can be good as a start to help you with this.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `ng-include`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: Kind of. <code>ng-include</code> will try to compile and display the html within the template, and this is causing an error. It seems to be due to the parameters that make up the directive do not exist.

In any case, <code>ng-include</code> seems to try to compile and display the code within the file/template and what I would like is for the contents to be displayed without being compiled; or see the contents as they appear in plain text within the file, not how they will be rendered in the application.

Comment: You could fetch the contents with `$http` service (GET) and set the result in the directives scope.

Comment: How would I extract the url from the attribute `directive.code` to be able to use it as the `$http.get()` url? If I try to access the variable within the scope parameter of the directive I get an error saying it cannot see the variable.

Comment: the directive usually shares the scope it is in, if you have isolated the scope, then you need to import the relevant parts in the isolated scope. `scope: {
  customerInfo: '=info'
},` will bind the `info` attribute on your directive to the `customerInfo` scope property. Look for isolated scope here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive If this is what you are looking for, I will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of trial and error and many thanks to everyone that commented I figured out a solution.

This is the js code:

`myApp.directive('directiveDetail', function($http){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/templates/directive-template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.directive.code) {
                $http.get(scope.directive.code).then(function (response) {
                    scope.displaycode = response.data;
                });
            }
        }
    }
});`

I needed to access the `scope` parameter to gain access to the URL data. I also needed to add the if statement because if I don't pass in a valid URL then the the text displayed is the entire code for the DOM.